# sklearn.tree.plot_tree show returns chunk of text instead of visualised tree

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, tree

I'm trying to show a tree visualisation using plot_tree, but it shows a chunk of text instead:

```
from sklearn.tree import plot_tree
plot_tree(t)
```

(where t is an instance of `DecisionTreeClassifier`)
This is the output:

```
[Text(464.99999999999994, 831.6, 'X[3] <= 0.8\nentropy = 1.581\nsamples = 120\nvalue = [39, 37, 44]'),
 Text(393.46153846153845, 646.8, 'entropy = 0.0\nsamples = 39\nvalue = [39, 0, 0]'),
```

and so on and so forth. How do I make it show the visual tree instead?
I'm using Jupyter 6.4.1 and I already imported matplotlib earlier in the code. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my case, it works with a simple "show":

```
plot_tree(t)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can plot your tree and specify the plot size of your tree with `plt.figure`

```
width = 10
height = 7
plt.figure(figsize=(width, height))

tree_plot_max_depth = 6
plot_tree(t, max_depth=tree_plot_max_depth)

## the key to the problem of not showing tree is the command below
plt.show()
```

And as the documentation is mentioned below you can specify more parameters for your tree to get a more informative image.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.plot_tree.html